# How to edit total supply after deployment? Parity

Tags: tokens, parity, contract-deployment

I was playing around in parity and deployed my own token. However,in total supply calculation I have made a mistake of not multiplying desired_supply * 10^decimals and ended up with less coins. How can I edit this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer depends on your smart contract. But assuming you're using a fairly standard ERC20 token contract, there's no way to modify the total supply.

Comment: Thank you. What about changing the token registry decimal in Parity. I've also registered the token on parity with 10 decimals. Is there a way to change that maybe?

Comment: Again, it's impossible to answer without seeing the code for your smart contract. But in general, code can't be changed after you deploy a smart contract, so the only changes that can happen are ones the code can do. If there's no function that changes the number of decimals (which I would hope there isn't :-P), then you can't change it.